# JwPlayer Make The Video Download Harder

Tags: video, download, jwplayer

I'm planning to buy JW Premium, but I do wondering that, is JW Premium prevent downloading the video?
I'm selling education videos from my web site, and I do not want customers to download it. 
I want to make it harder at least.
is JW Premium the right answer for me?

Answer (score 1):

Some things that might help:

- Using a chunked format (HLS or MPEG DASH) for your videos, instead of MP4 files. This will make it difficult for people to download (they would have to put it back together.) JW Player's premium version supports these formats.
- Using some sort of DRM. I think JW Player supports this, but I've never used it.